# Vue Error in Laravel Blade: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

I have checked the other SO questions, and their questions are not the same as mine.

I have at the bottom of many Laravel Blade files a small snippet of JS code which simply shows and hides an alert.  For example:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).slideUp(500);
        });
</script>
```

The views giving the error have absolutely nothing to do with the Vuejs template nor the View where the Vuejs template is being presented. They are completely different and separate. Nevertheless, Vue complains about this in the console. If I remove the snippet from the view, then Vuejs is happy. I have checked the HTML of the source code of the View giving the error, in the W3 checker and  whilst it did complain about a few trivial things there were no unclosed tags. I really don't want to have to pull all these snippets out and put them in a separate file wrapped in a function, so I hope someone has some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Try writing your `<script>` as `<script type="application/javascript">` and tell me if the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have read this suggestion in several places and the common opinion is that is does eliminate the error but in many cases it also prevents the Jquery / JS from running. So, in the end I bit the bullet and I ripped the snippets out and replaced them in a separate file wrapped in a function. Thank you  !